# Dynamic Insert MSSQL Procedure

Tags: sql-server, json, stored-procedures

Is there any way to create a stored procedure take two parameters (Table_Name, Rows) rows will be in standard format like json for example:-

```
INSERT("TABLENAME","{{id:1,Code:'AA'},{id:2,Code'BB'}}")
```

or any other format. the goal is "creating one procedure for simple insert"

thank you

Comment: You would need to generate the insert as a string then use sp_execute_sql or EXEC to execute it. Your stored procedure would take two VARCHAR parameters. It would be vulnerable to a SQL Injection attack though. If you want to simplify things you may wish to consider building UPSERT logic into your SP or using the MERGE statement. This will update if it exists or insert if it doesn't'

Comment: MERGE statement is good idea thanks, but is there any ready-made procedure to avoid repeat cycle

Comment: You might be able to find one online. Your first step would be to take the table name (it could even be in the JSON) and make the string `'INSERT INTO ' + @TableName` in a stored procedure' Why don't you try that much and post it back.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to search for TVP to achive this goal.
With help of TVP (Table valued parameter), you need to pass only one parameter in SQL Stored procedure, so insted of creating Json string in code behind, create datatable.